# Is there a way to auotmatically build a sublime project?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way to automatically  create a .sublime-project given a filesystem/ folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new window, select `Project -> Add Folder to Project...`, add your desired folder(s). Then, go to `Project -> Save Project As...` and save it. You can then go to `Project -> Edit Project` and use any of the options described [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) (ST2) or [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html) (ST3).